# Check if a string is the anagram of another

Tags: code-golf, string

## Skat

I'm a fan of anagrams, so given two strings `s1` and `s2` write a program or function that outputs a truthy value if `s2` is an anagram of `s1`, and a falsey value otherwise (not accounting for spaces and capital letters).

For example:

Input: `s1 = "Anagram"; s2 = "Nag a ram"`

```
true
```

Input: `s1 = "stack overflow"; s2 = "fewer kool cats"`

```
false
```

Input: `s1 = "apple rocks"; s2 = "paler spock"`

```
true
```

## Rules

- Program and function allowed.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

Duck logo!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
lðδKJ€{Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5/CGc1u8vR41rak@3P3/f7S6Y15ielFirrqOgrpfYrpCogKIEwsA)

Comment: Wow, your answer and mine are literal polar opposites at the same cost; you remove spaces, I add them. Yours is definitely more efficient though. I'm removing mine, this was so much better lol.

Comment: If you sort first you can just remove the trailing newlines and dont have to join afterwards. tl;dr: `l€{ðδÛË` should also work (1 byte saving yay)

Comment: @Datboi Hmm, well, I'll rather answer the original challenge with that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒlḟṢ¥€⁶E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJyHO@Y/3Lno0NJHTWseNW5z/f//f7S6Y15ielFirrqOgrpfYrpCogKIEwsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
def f(a,b):print(g(a)==g(b))
g=lambda a:sorted(a.upper().replace(" ", ""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDsMgDADAva@wPNlSlKVbJMY8xARDkSAgh0bq62l74/XPeLXzOWfQCJFk8bx1y@egRMLOJfLMj@SKVB8EZLuaDQ0k67t3NeLVtBc5lBBwAUTmGQmr2NHgzkPK/u87Q1GoAr81GII8vw)

Comment: You can change `def f(a,b):print(g(a)==g(b))` for `lambda a,b:g(a)==g(b)`

Comment: You missed an extra space after `.replace()`'s comma.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
v rS á øVv rS
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=diByUyDhIPhWdiByUw==&input=IkFuYWdyYW0iCiJOYWcgYSByYW0i)